# Reloading live charts chart only adds new data

Tags: c#, loading, livecharts

I'm using Live Charts in my application for a pareto chart. I have made a SeriesCollection. I'm loading it from a Stored Procedure in the following way:

```
public void LoadChart()
{
    List<DataTops> dataTops = GetTops();
    ChartValues<int> Pareto = new ChartValues<int>();
    List<string> timevalues = new List<string>();
    int selected = ComboSelect();
    IDLables = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in dataTops)
    {
        values.Add(item.Total);
        Pareto.Add(item.Running);
        IDLables.Add((item.W) + "." + (item.B));
    }

    TopAlarms = new SeriesCollection
    {
        new ColumnSeries
        {
            Title = "Total",
            Values =values,
            DataLabels = false,
            ScalesYAt = 0,
        },

        new LineSeries
        {
            Title = "%",
            Values = Pareto,
            ScalesYAt = 1,
            PointGeometrySize = 0
        }
    };

public List<DataTops> GetTops()
    {
        int selected = ComboSelect();

        DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
        DataSetTableAdapters.TimePerID_TopTableAdapter TimerTopta = new DataSetTableAdapters.TimePerID_TopTableAdapter();
        TimerTopta.Fill(Ds.TimePerID_Top, selected);
        List<DataTops> Tops = new List<DataTops>();
        foreach (DataRow row in Ds.Tables["TimePerID_Top"].Rows)
        {
            Tops.Add(new DataTops() { Total = (int)row["Total"], W = (int)row["W"], B = (int)row["B"], Amount = (int)row["Amount"], Running = (int)row["Running"] });
        }
        return Tops;
    }
```

I have a combobox to select an amount to show (`selected` in the dataset) and a button that I use to update the chart. The Chart works fine, but whenever I press the update button it only adds new data behind the already existing data.

Live charts doesn't automatically clear the chart collection data upon loading so I did this:

```
private void UpdateChart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TopAlarms != null)
        {
            TopAlarms.Clear();

        }
        LoadChart();
    }
```

But it still won't clear and reload the chart. How can i reload the chart when the button is pressed so the new selected data amount will show?

Answer (score 0):

after some testing and reasearch I have the following solution for clearing the chart:

```
try
{
    if (TopAlarms != null)
    {
        TopAlarms.Clear();

    }
}
catch { }
```

This is probably not the best solution but it works for me.